# PayPal Sandbox -Amount not deduct on test purchase of any thing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, sandbox, paypal-sandbox

I have setup a Personal and Business account using Paypal Sandbox. When I run a test purchase for, for example,$309539.24, in Business account balance and $4740.01 in Personal account balance. when i m purchase any thing purchasing process is running successfully. but no amount deduct and add in personal sandbox account and business sandbox account. paypal sandbox profile is successfully created.

Comment: You're gonna have to describe how you do it and show us some code if we're going to be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the transaction history for both the accounts(i.e the Seller and the Buyer)?
Is the transaction/ purchase showing up there?

**This is how you create sandbox accounts for testing.**

Go to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/
Login to your account.

Under 'Sandbox', click on 'Test Accounts'
[image]

For creating a new test account, you have two options:
1) Preconfigured
2) Create Manually

Click on 'Preconfigured'. Fill in the details, and hit on 'Create Account'

Follow the same steps to create the 2nd account.

*Best practise is to name one account as 'seller' and the other as 'buyer'
This will avoid any confusion*

---

**Creating buttons and making purchases:**

Click on Seller's account. Enter the password and login.

Go to 'Merchant Services' tab to create the product/button for Seller.

*NOTE:For some reason, clicking on the 'Merchant Services' logs you out of that account.
Probably some issue with the PayPal's Sandbox site.*

The alternative to this is to go to 'My Account' => click on Profile => Selling Preferences => My Saved Buttons => Create new button

After you finish entering the details of the product, click on 'Create Button'
You will get the HTML snippet. Paste this in a notepad file, and save it with the '.html' extension.
[image]

Open the file in the browser, click on the button to purchase the product.
Click on CheckOut with PayPal. Login with Buyer's account, and complete the purchase.

This will affect the account balances of both the Seller and the Buyer.
And you will be able to see the transaction in both the Seller and Buyers Account(Under 'Overview' or 'History')

Hope it helps you out.

Thank you.